# stream uploading an gm-resized image to s3 with aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, streaming

so what i want to do is to stream an image from a url, process it with graphicsmagick and stream-upload it to s3. i just dont get it working.

streaming the processed image to local disk (using fs.createWriteStream) works without a problem.

when i buffer my stream, the final image in s3 has at least the expected size (kb-wise), but i can not open that image.

thats my current progress:

```
var request = require('request');

var gm = require("gm");

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var mime = require('mime');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

gm(request('http://www.some-domain.com/some-image.jpg'), "my-image.jpg")
  .resize("100^", "100^")
  .stream(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var str = '';
    stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       str += data;
    });
    stdout.on('end', function(data) {
      var data = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "my-image.jpg",
        Body: new Buffer(str, 'binary'), // thats where im probably wrong
        ContentType: mime.lookup("my-image.jpg")
      };
      s3.client.putObject(data, function(err, res) {
        console.log("done");
      });
    });
  });
```

i did try some stuff like creating a filewritestream and filereadstream, but i think there should be some cleaner an nicer solution to that problem...

EDIT: the first thing i tried was setting the Body to stdout (the suggested answer from @AndyD):

```
var data = {
    Bucket: "my-bucket",
    Key: "my-image.jpg",
    Body: stdout,
    ContentType: mime.lookup("my-image.jpg")
  };
```

but that returns following error:

```
Cannot determine length of [object Object]'
```

EDIT2:

- nodeversion: 0.8.6 (i also tried 0.8.22 and 0.10.0)
- aws-sdk: 0.9.7-pre.8 (installed today)

the complete err:

```
{ [Error: Cannot determine length of [object Object]]
  message: 'Cannot determine length of [object Object]',
  object:
  { _handle:
   { writeQueueSize: 0,
    owner: [Circular],
    onread: [Function: onread] },
 _pendingWriteReqs: 0,
 _flags: 0,
 _connectQueueSize: 0,
 destroyed: false,
 errorEmitted: false,
 bytesRead: 0,
 _bytesDispatched: 0,
 allowHalfOpen: undefined,
 writable: false,
 readable: true,
 _paused: false,
 _events: { close: [Function], error: [Function: handlerr] } },
name: 'Error' }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you don't need to read the stream yourself (in your case you seem to be converting from binary to string and back due to var str='' and then appending data which is a binary buffer etc...

Try letting putObject pipe the stream like this:

```
gm(request('http://www.some-domain.com/some-image.jpg'), "my-image.jpg")
  .resize("100^", "100^")
  .stream(function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      var data = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "my-image.jpg",
        Body: stdout
        ContentType: mime.lookup("my-image.jpg")
      };
      s3.client.putObject(data, function(err, res) {
        console.log("done");
      });
    });
  });
```

See these [release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/4656127103016393) for more info.

If streaming/pipe doesn't work then something like this might which will load everything into memory and then upload. You're limited to 4Mb I think in this case.

```
    var buf = new Buffer('');
    stdout.on('data', function(data) {
       buf = Buffer.concat([buf, data]);
    });
    stdout.on('end', function(data) {
      var data = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket",
        Key: "my-image.jpg",
        Body: buf,
        ContentType: mime.lookup("my-image.jpg")
      };
      s3.client.putObject(data, function(err, res) {
        console.log("done");
      });
    });
```

Comment: that was the first thing i tried, because stdout should already be a stream right? but that doesnt work, 'err' in the last callback says 'Cannot determine length of [object Object]' ;-(

Comment: have you got a stacktrace? Are you using the latest version of aws-SDK?

Comment: no, that is all i got. i think there is an issue with the aws-sdk, i opened one on their github-page: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/94

Comment: your buffer example works (when you instantiate the Buffer with an empty string 'new Buffer("")'. i will accept and upvote your answer, because that helped to solve my original question. of course i would prefer a true streaming solution, but i think thats an aws-sdk issue. thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks. You can also use knox + knox-mpu (multipart upload) modules to do the streaming but I prefer the official sdk now.