# Memory buffers fills up when I stream upload a file, though passing a disk storage location param

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js

Trying to stream-upload to S3 using skipper and skipper-s3 using this code

```
image_upload : function  (req,res) {

    // depends on bodyparser:skipper in confing/http.js

    console.log("Uploading image .. ");

    req.file('image')
        .upload({
            adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
            key: KEY,
            secret: SECRET,
            bucket: 'mybucket',
            tmpdir: 'tmp/s3-multiparts'
        }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err){
                return res.negotiate(err);
            } else {
                dict = {
                    files: uploadedFiles,
                    textParams: req.params.all()
                }
                return res.ok(dict);
            }
        }

    );
};
```

**I have 2 problems:**

**First**: when I try to upload some file, I can see that this file buffers in memory, instead just buffering to the disk (path added to options).

Actually this is a big problem, as my memory will fill up so quickly when having many users concurrently uploading

**Second**: my application crashes when upload is bigger than 5MBs, giving me this error

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (~Desktop/myApp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:175:17)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:279:11)
    at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (_http_server.js:292:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your **second problem:**
You can specify maximum size of file to be uploaded. Default is 5 MB.

```
req.file('some_file').upload({
    dirname: 'path to store the file',/* optional. defaults to assets/uploads I guess*/
    saveAs: 'new file name', /* optional. default file name */
    maxBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024 //5 MB
}, function(err, uploadedFiles) {

});
```

I am not sure about the first problem though. You don't need to specify a tempdir in options. `Skipper-S3` by default writes the file to `<your project root>/.tmp/s3-upload-part-queue` for its upload purpose. I don't see why the memory should get filled up. Can you possibly remove the  `tempdir` and check?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried with and without the tmpDir, it makes no difference, it keeps loading/buffering the uploaded file to the memory

Comment: @securecurve Quoting from skipper docs, not sure if it is of any help; >The path to the directory where buffering multipart requests can rest their heads. Amazon requires "parts" sent to their multipart upload API to be at least 5MB in size, so this directory is used to queue up chunks of data until a big enough payload has accumulated. Defaults to .tmp/s3-upload-part-queue (resolved from the current working directory of the node process- e.g. your app)

Comment: Maybe, you can avoid using `skipper-s3` and  write the file to disk, then use `aws-sdk` for uploading to S3

Comment: Yes, I read this part in the documentation, that's why I turned disk buffering on, the main problem here is memory buffering is happening along the way, which is a negative thing, because this means I will need a big memory and at the same time a waste to the disk space that's already used for this

Comment: btw, I tried you suggested solution `maxBytes` but didn't work out. Probably this is not intended for skipper-s3

Comment: I can confirm that `maxBytes` is effective only to disk uploads and NOT skipper-s3 uploads

Comment: I tried your idea Mjzac, which is uploading the files to disk first then uploading them to S3 using aws-sdk `s3Client.upload`, yet, the contents still buffer to memory before it reaches Amazon