# The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-type

I'm trying to upload a file (pdf/jpg) using a Lambda function written in NodeJS by triggering the request from Postman but I'm getting the following error:-

```
2022-02-02T15:09:51.135Z    743939db-7511-4003-8e49-40c95ada47b4    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined",
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined",
        "    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)",
        "    at Function.from (buffer.js:334:9)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.lambdaHandler [as handler] (/var/task/app.js:68:23)"
    ]
}
```

The following is a chunk of event object getting logged on the CloudWatch:-

```
2022-02-02T20:39:52.136+05:30

Copy
info: Event:: {"body":"{\n    \"base64String\": \"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAcHBwcIBwgJCQgMDAsMDBEQDg4QERoSFBIUEhonGB0YGB0YJyMqIiAiKiM+MSsrMT5IPDk8SFdOTldtaG2Pj8ABBwcHBwgHCAkJCAwMCwwMERAODhARGhIUEhQSGicYHRgYHRgnIyoiICIqIz4xKysxPkg8OTxIV05OV21obY+PwP/CABEICHAPAAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABwgBBQYEAwL/2gAIAQEAAAAAsiAA
```

**Lambda (NodeJS code):-**

```
'use-strict'

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const logger = require('./logger').logger;

const moment = require('moment');

const fileType = ('file-type');

const { Buffer } = require('buffer');

//const { fileTypeFromFile } = 'file-type';

const ddbTable = process.env.RUNTIME_DDB_TABLE_FREE_USER_DOCUMENT;

const s3TempBucket = process.env.RUNTIME_S3_TEMP_BUCKET;

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const getFile = (fileMime, buffer, userId) => {
  let fileExt = fileMime.ext;
  let hash = sha1(new Buffer(new Date().toString()));
  let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

  let filePath = hash + '/';
  let fileName = unixTime(now) + '.' + fileExt;
  let fileFullName = filePath + fileName;
  let fileFullPath = s3TempBucket + userId + fileFullName;

  const params = {
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: s3TempBucket,
    Key: fileName
  };

  let uploadFile = {
    size: buffer.toString('ascii').length,
    type: fileMime.mime,
    name: fileName,
    fullPath: fileFullPath
  }

  return {
    'params': params,
    'uploadFile': uploadFile
  }
}

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  logger.info("Event::", event);
  logger.info('Uploading file to bucket::', s3TempBucket);

  let body, data;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
  };

  let request = JSON.parse(event.body);
  let base64String = await request.base64String;
  logger.info("base64String::", base64String);

  let buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');

  //let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64');
  let fileMime = fileType(buffer);
  logger.info(fileMime);

  if (fileMime === null) {
    return context.fail('String supplied is not file type');
  }

  //let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer, user.id);
  let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer, 'b06eb6f4-0ff0-5cb5-a41c-e000af66c8e9');
  let params = file.params;

  try {
    //await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.putObject(params, (err, results) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else {
          console.log(results);
          body = results;
          resolve(results)
        }
      });
   // });

  } catch (err) {
    logger.info(err);
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
    return err;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };

}
```

The base64String is coming as undefined not sure why as I can see clearly in the event object?:-

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
```

Please assist, thanks

**Postman request:-**

[image]

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807339/upload-a-binary-file-to-s3-using-aws-sdk-for-node-js

Comment: @shimo I have gone through with that link and tried attempting it but that solution will not work as it requires middleware like express but here I'm looking for a pure Lambda-based solution... I had researched a lot but did not find a single solution on the web for the last 3 weeks that gives a NodeJS based Lambda to upload a file...and I'm really frustrating to be honest

Comment: Sorry about that. I've post an answer that use sample of Lambda repository. Anyway it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use API Gateway, *you don't need base64 encode because API Gateway does automatically*.

A sample is provided in AWS.

1. Select Create function
2. Select Browse serverless app repository
3. Find "uploader: Serverless web application for uploading files to
   S3"
4. Deploy

[uploader's github](https://github.com/evanchiu/serverless-galleria/tree/master/uploader)

This creates API gateway and NodeJS Lambda. (You need to provide S3 bucket.)

The instruction says that to upload a file, open InvokeURL in browser and drag drop a file. You can do this with Postman too as follows.

1. Input `POST InvokeURL/api/file/text.pdf`.
2. Set body KEY to File and input text.pdf. Select the pdf file as VALUE.
3. Send

You can find the code in index.js and extract what you need.